# Hide SideBar Floating Sharing Bar When Not Maximized

Tags: css, sidebar

I've added a code to my blogger for a sharing bar, it works fine but I'd like to have it not be visible when the window is not maximized. What would I need to change to accomplish this?

```
<style>
#pageshare {position:fixed; bottom:15%; right:10px; float:left; border: 1px solid #999999; border-radius:5px;-moz-border-radius:5px;-webkit-border-radius:5px;background-color:#e5e5e5;padding:0 0 2px 0;z-index:10;}

#pageshare .sbutton {float:left;clear:both;margin:5px 5px 0 5px;}
.fb_share_count_top {width:48px !important;}
.fb_share_count_top, .fb_share_count_inner {-moz-border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;}
.FBConnectButton_Small, .FBConnectButton_RTL_Small {width:49px !important; -moz-border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;}
.FBConnectButton_Small .FBConnectButton_Text {padding:2px 2px 3px !important;-moz-border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;font-size:8px;}
</style>
<br/><div id='pageshare' title="Share This With Your Friends">
<div class='sbutton' id='gb'><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like layout="box_count" show_faces="false" font=""></fb:like></div>
<br/><div class='sbutton' id='rt'><a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="vertical" >Tweet</a><script src='http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js' type="text/javascript"></script></div>
<br/><div class='sbutton' id='gplusone'><script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script><g:plusone size="tall"></g:plusone></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `but I´d like to have it gone`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a media query?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
#pageshare{
    display: none;
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. where exactly do I need to add the change? sorry I'm not good at this...

Comment: You can put it below the other styles you have there, and you can change the width to whatever width you think is suitable as your "not-maximised" screen width

Comment: I've changed the number many times but it's still visible when minimized. The thing is when the window is too small the bar is shown over the articles and not moving at all. Is there a way to stick the bar to left side of the website? so it wouldn't be visible when the window is getting smaller. Second option: provide me with a better code with these features. Thank you in advance!

Comment: In the first bit of your code, change where it says "right: 10px;" to left: 10px